# Windows phone 8.1 app crashing while using libphonenumber-csharp

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, nuget, libphonenumber

I am trying to use libphonenumber-csharp library for my windows phone project for validating international phone numbers. I have installed the library using the following command on nuget package manager console:

```
Install-Package libphonenumber-csharp
```

I am using the following click event handler to test the functionality of the library:

```
private void buttonCall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String bdNumberStr = "0123456789";
    PhoneNumbers.PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
    try
    {
        PhoneNumbers.PhoneNumber numberProto = phoneUtil.Parse(bdNumberStr, "BD");
    }
    catch (PhoneNumbers.NumberParseException exc)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("NumberParseException was thrown: " + exc.Message);
    }
}
```

The program is crashing after clicking the button. The event handler function is not getting hit and an exception is thrown. In output window it says something like the following:-

> Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs{60688B3F-2E3D-46EE-B0DE-C1F3E22F0912}\Install\PhoneNumbers.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Does anyone have an idea whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this package, this library built for desktops, not for Windows Phone or Store apps.
You need to port it by yourself or find another solution.